# FileNotFoundException vs. NoSuchFileException

Tags: java, exception, io

I noticed another Java exception for indicating that file does not exist - `NoSuchFileException`. I was tasked to refactor  a certain api which throws both of these from differen methods and I would like to use just one.

Should I map `NoSuchFileException` to file to `FileNotFoundException` ? Should I use `NoSuchFileException` instead of `FileNotFoudnException` because it is more specific?

EDIT: Updated the question. I read the documentation before posting this question and know the basic difference. I was hoping for additional information and the guidance in this case since exception handling by type is important for the clients of the service api and I would like to avoid the case when the check needs to be done for both exception types.

Comment: Did you read the specs for them?

Comment: The Java 7 exception NoSuchFileException is used only when the requested file does not exist; the earlier version FileNotFoundException was used for that and also for cases where the file does exist but can't be accessed for some reason.

Comment: One is for use with the File class; the other is for use with the Path class.  Their packages should have made that clear.  Note that you should not be catching either of those exceptions;  you should be checking for a file's existence/readability before attempting to read it.

Comment: @VGR I disagree. You should be catching these exceptions wherever relevant, because the file might be deleted by another thread/process inbetween your existence check and your attempt to read it.

Comment: @Zero3 There is always the possibility of external influences.  That's why the exceptions exist.  But you should not use them to check for a file's existence.  More generally, exceptions are more resource-expensive than `if` statements, and should not be relied upon for program flow control.

Comment: @VGR I must disagree again. That is not why the exceptions exist. It is perfectly reasonable to catch and handle such exceptions as part of your normal control flow. Especially if you assume that the file exist, and do not want to handle the case that it does not in two different places. OP never wrote that his intention was to use the exceptions to check for the existence of a file. If that is your purpose, then of course you can use methods directly intended for that.

Comment: @VGR Also, the performance argument is a little off. Any speed difference between if statements and exceptions are dwarfed by the cost of doing IO.  And checking whether the file exists prior to opening it is actually additional overhead you skip by catching the exception instead. Either way, I would argue that solid and readable code is much more important than this kind of microoptimization.

Answer (score 8):

[FileNotFoundException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileNotFoundException.html)

> Signals that an attempt to open the file denoted by a specified pathname has failed.
>   This exception will be thrown by the `FileInputStream`, `FileOutputStream`, and `RandomAccessFile` constructors when a file with the specified pathname does not exist. **It will also be thrown by these constructors if the file does exist but for some reason is inaccessible**, for example when an attempt is made to open a read-only file for writing.

[NoSuchFileException](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/nio/javadoc/java/nio/file/NoSuchFileException.html)

> Checked exception thrown when an attempt is made to access a file that does not exist.

The documentation is self-explanatory.

Comment: It made it preety clear. FileNotFound should have been FileNotAccesible or something , it seems Java trying to correct this in java 7, it cannot just remove FileNotFound , may be Java 9 they will deprecate it.

Comment: Seems like a javadoc for the FileNotFoundException is not up-to-date, because FileReader's constructor throws FileNotFoundException as well, while it is not mentioned in the exception's javadoc.

Comment: @VadymPechenoha: I assume that the JavaDoc isn't trying to provide an exhaustive list here. IMHO, there are some other standard classes/methods that can throw this exception.

Answer (score 6):

Unlike `NoSuchFileException`, `FileNotFoundException` does not necessarily mean that file doesn't exist, it might just be inaccessible. Apart from that I am not sure how thy're any different.

Answer (score 4):

IMHO, there is a nuance in the semantics of those two exceptions.
`NoSuchFileException` is generally used when there is no File at the expected location while
`FileNotFoundException` is used as well for this case, but also in the case the file is present but can't be accessed. (permission issue,etc ...)

Moreover, note that `NoSuchFileException` was introduced in Java 7, thus for your specific task, I'd stick to `FileNoteFoundException` as it's more general and compatible with Java 1.6

Answer (score 1):

`NoSuchFileException` extends the new (as of 1.7) `FileSystemException` subclass of `IOException` while `FileNotFoundException` is a direct subclass of `IOException`. As a new parent class, `FileSystemException` should be as complete as possible, hence the addition of `NoSuchFileException`, despite the  appearance of redundancy. The `NotDirectoryException` and `AccessDeniedException` subclasses flesh out the earlier functionality nicely, rather than leaving the several possibilities in one undistinguishable clump.