# What will readAllLines return if the file does not exist?

Tags: java, file

The oracle docs says [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset)) that the `Files.readAllLines(Path path, Charset cs)` method returns the lines from a file as a `List<String>`.
What will it return if the file does not exist? Also which implementation of `List<String>` will it return?

Comment: `IOException`, probably, and the `List<String>` type is _deliberately_ unspecified and subject to change.  (I'd bet on an `unmodifiableList` wrapper around an `ArrayList`, though.)

Comment: @LouisWasserman: So I can't be sure whether `List.get()`  will be O(n) or O(1) for the returned `List`?

Comment: @ln78 I wouldn't worry about that; you should feel fairly comfortable assuming it's O(1), just not whether it's modifiable or not.

Comment: Yes, though I suspect it will be ArrayList.

Comment: You can do `List<String> randomList = list instanceof RandomAccess ? list : new ArrayList<>(list);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What will it return if the file does not exist?

It will not "return" anything.
As the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset)) says it, the `readAllLines` method will throw an `IOException` in case of I/O errors.

Specifically, when the file doesn't exist, the implementation of JDK 8 that I'm using happens to throw a `java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException`, which is a sub-class of `IOException`.

> Also which implementation of `List<String>` will it return?

That's really not your concern. This is why interfaces and encapsulation exists, so you don't look inside. The important thing is that it's an object respecting the contract of the [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interface.

If you must know, you can check by calling `.getClass()` on the returned object. The implementation of JDK 8 that I'm using happens to return `java.util.ArrayList`. Another implementation might return something else. As I mentioned earlier, we should not even try to see what it is, to avoid any shred of risk of breaking encapsulation.

Comment: Actually, according to the Javadoc, "whether the List is modifiable or not is implementation dependent and therefore not specified," although in my implementation, it is also `java.util.ArrayList`.

Answer (score 3):

Here are the exceptions thrown by `Files#readAllLines(Path, Charset)`

It actually uses a try-with-ressources instantiating a `BufferedReader` with the `path` as parameter. If the file does not exist, an `IOException` is than thrown by it within the constructor.

> Throws:
>
> `java.io.IOException` **if an I/O error occurs reading from the file** or a
>   malformed or unmappable byte sequence is read
>
> `java.lang.SecurityException` In the case of the default provider, and a
>   security manager is installed, the checkRead method is invoked to
>   check read access to the file.

---

An `ArrayList<String>` is used as the exact implementation of `List<String>`

```
public static List<String> readAllLines(Path path, Charset cs) throws IOException {
    try (BufferedReader reader = newBufferedReader(path, cs)) {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();           <-------- HERE
        for (;;) {
             String line = reader.readLine();
             if (line == null)
                 break;
             result.add(line);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple enough to test?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException
```

As to the return value's actual type. The return signature just says List and that's all you can trust. Having said that the current Oracle class libraries return ArrayList:

```
List<String> readAllLines = Files.readAllLines(path, Charset.defaultCharset());
System.out.println(readAllLines.getClass());
```

Gives the output:

```
class java.util.ArrayList
```

Which in the source can be seen by:

```
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

It will throw `NoSuchFileException` if the file does not exist. You can learn more about `NoSuchFileException`s [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27424237/filenotfoundexception-vs-nosuchfileexception).

Comment: Actually no, not in any current jvm at least, it will throw a java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException

Comment: you might be using JDK7 or JDK8.

Comment: Well your answer initially just plainly stated FileNotFoundException and I replied with not in any current jvm. Even 7 is officially end of life.

Comment: Besides neither the  Files class nor  readAllLines api existed in Java 6.

Comment: @MattiasIsegranBergander, you are right..i made mistakes. neither the Files class nor readAllLines api existed in Java 6. Thanks